# How to close active ion-fab list container programmatically?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

On the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab#methods) it shows that I can use `close()` to ‘Close an active FAB list container.’, but how do I integrate that to my typescript file? ie. what do I have to import and how do I reference to the FAB button?

Answer (score 1):

you can use viewchild to trigger it like this :

on html file

```
  <ion-fab vertical="center" horizontal="center" slot="fixed" #fab>
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="share"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
    <ion-fab-list side="top">
      <ion-fab-button><ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon></ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
    <ion-fab-list side="bottom">
      <ion-fab-button
        ><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon
      ></ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
    <ion-fab-list side="start">
      <ion-fab-button
        ><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon
      ></ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
    <ion-fab-list side="end">
      <ion-fab-button><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>

  <ion-button (click)="onClose()"> close</ion-button>
```

on ts file

```
  @ViewChild('fab') fab: IonFab;

  constructor() {}

  onClose() {
    this.fab.close();
  }
```

and here the working sample [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-umspzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)